# Very important peace lily not growing at all

Tags: houseplants

My boyfriend has a peace lily from his 12 year old daughters funeral that was 6 years ago (we have been together a little over a year now) I have cut brown spots off, I need to again. I water 1-2 times a week. It doesn't grow at all. I also just placed it by the door for some light today. Any suggestions would be helpful.  I thought of re potting it but if I kill it , it would really bother me. Hoping I can add pics[image: short browning not growing]

Answer (score 1):

There are several things that could be going on with your Peace Lily.

Over watering can be an issue. As a general rule, you should allow the top 1-2 inches of soil to dry between watering. I also noticed that the plant is in a grower pot that sits inside another pot. Water draining out of the drainage holes in the growers pot will collect in the bottom the outer pot, causing the soil to stay too wet. You can add some rocks (I like to use river rocks) to the bottom of the outer pot to help keep the plant from sitting in water but you should also be careful to empty the water from the outer pot about 30 minutes after watering.

Peace lilies can be sensitive to chlorine and fluoride that is found in tap water. I recommend using distilled water. That is the best way to solve water quality problems such as chlorine and fluoride, which many plants are sensitive to. These chemicals in the water causes the brown leaf tips.

Peace Lilies need bright, indirect light, but no direct sunlight. The plant needs lots of light to flower.

I noticed that a few of the leaves look like they have been chewed on. Do you have a dog or a cat in the house? Peace Lily is considered a poisonous plant.

There are almost no 'safe' plants. Any plant can cause harm to children and animals if chewed or ingested. No matter if it is considered poisonous or not. Even 'safe' nonpoisonous plants can cause stomach upset, skin rash, lip/tongue swelling or could cause a potentially fatal allergic reaction. Especially in young children, puppies and/or kittens.
It is always best to keep all houseplants in a place out of reach of children and pets.

I am very sorry for your boyfriend's loss. Hopefully this will help keep the Peace Lily a healthy, flowering memento.

Answer (score -1):

They always say peace lillies need bright indirect light, which is most of my house, but ive always had the best luck having them grow in a low light, sometimes I feel like thats wrong because literally everyone says bright indirect light. So I put it in that light setting a few days and the tips start turning brown. I have an app on my phone called Plantera that helps keep track of water and other info. It has be water based on the pot, type of plant and lighting. For my peace lily it has me keeping the soil staying moist, but not soaked. The app also gives advice on when to fertilize and how often to repot, type of soil etc. I used to not think this was an important thing, as well as repotting with new soil, but I have seen so much growth this summer on 30+ plant types by doing this. Pruning damaged or dying leaves when they are ready will also allow the plant to give energy into growing new leaves.